# Is there any query to set identity specification to false or true

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, identity-column

I am trying to edit a table structure. I have a table that contains a primary key and its identity specification is true. I want to change the primary key's identity specification to false using a query as long as I want to run this query on the user's program as I can't go for every user's PC and change it from the designer ... I just want a query to change it from identity specification true to false.

Can I use

```
alter table table1 set table1ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Adding New Column First -

```
alter table tablename add columnname int
```

2- Copying the data from identity to column to new column added using above query -

```
update tablename set columnname = identitycolumnname
```

3- Now Dropping identity column -

```
alter table tablename drop column identitycolumnname
```

4- Finally renaming a new column inserted to a identity Column name

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'tablename.columnname' , 'identitycolumnname', 'COLUMN'
```